# angular seven database connectivity error

Tags: angular7

```
compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'AngularFirestore' imported by the module 
 'AppModule'.



Please add a 
     @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2430)
    at compiler.js:18645
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:18620)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:26029)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:26010)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:25970)
    at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:143)
    at compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ (core.js:17619)
    at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:17802)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:2430
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:18645
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:18620
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules @ compiler.js:26029
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:26010
push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:25970
push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:143
compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__ @ core.js:17619
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:17802
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:9
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:78
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1e
```

I added the angular module in ng module but problem is same

Comment: Can you add your code of `app.module.ts` in the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `AngularFireModule` also into your `app.module.ts`

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

....
imports: [
AngularFireModule.initializeApp({
  apiKey: YOUR_API_KEY,
  authDomain: YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: YOUR_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: YOUR_PROJECT_ID
}),
AngularFirestoreModule,
...
]
```

Comment: maine already import ki huyi hai angualrfiremodule but problm is same

Comment: can you post your app.module.ts file